# Nginx Bad Gateway after altering project structure

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, nginx, wsgi, gunicorn

I have a django app hosted on AWS and have been cleaning up some aspects of the project structure. One of these cleanups involved removing a parent folder in the root directory and putting my appspec.yml file (used for CodeDeploy) in the folder with docs. So I am going from this:

`myproject/
    appspec.yml
    myproject/
        requirements/
        docs/
        myproject/
            manage.py
            myproject/
                __init__.py
                urls.py
                wsgi.py
                settings/
                myproject/
                    __init__.py
                    myproject.py`

To this:

`myproject/
    appspec.yml
    requirements/
    docs/
    myproject/
        manage.py
        myproject/
            __init__.py
            urls.py
            wsgi.py
            settings/
            myproject/
                __init__.py
                myproject.py`

I made the following prior to rebooting the instance:

1. Changed `gunicorn.conf` location from `root /var/www/myproject/myproject/myproject/myproject` to `root /var/www/myproject/myproject/myproject`
2. Changed `nginx.conf` location from `root /var/www/myproject/myproject/myproject/myproject` to `root /var/www/myproject/myproject/myproject`

I am now seeing **502 BAD GATEWAY** when I try to access my website URL and seeing `failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream`when looking at nginx `error.log`.

This clearly happened because I messed with the project directories. Did I miss something else that needs to change or was it just a bad idea to change the directories in the first place?

**Current nginx.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  www.myproject.co;
    return 301 http://myproject.co$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myproject.co;

    ##Deny illegal Host headers
    if ($host !~* ^(myproject.co)$ ) {
        return 444;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /var/www/myproject/myproject/myproject;
    }
    location /media/ {
        root /var/www/myproject/myproject/myproject;
    }


    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
}
```

**Current gunicorn.conf**

```
description "Gunicorn application server handling myproject"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
setuid ubuntu
setgid ubuntu
chdir /var/www/myproject/myproject/myproject

exec /usr/local/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 myproject.wsgi:application --env SECRET_KEY=""
```

**Traceback Error**

When I run `exec /usr/local/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 myproject.wsgi:application --env SECRET_KEY=""`, I get the following error:

```
exec /usr/local/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 myproject.wsgi:application --env SECRET_KEY="f15a4d7s4bec9cnlw24sw2lj4ften12nu3e4cx3z1utqgajp87"
[2017-01-20 16:02:49 +0000] [9809] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.4.5
[2017-01-20 16:02:49 +0000] [9809] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (9809)
[2017-01-20 16:02:49 +0000] [9809] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2017-01-20 16:02:49 +0000] [10039] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10039
[2017-01-20 16:02:49 +0000] [10039] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 515, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 122, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 130, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 357, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/var/www/myproject/myproject/myproject/myproject/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .myproject import app as celery_app
ImportError: cannot import name app
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 515, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 122, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 130, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 357, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/var/www/myproject/myproject/myproject/myproject/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .myproject import app as celery_app
ImportError: cannot import name app
[2017-01-20 16:02:49 +0000] [10039] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10039)
[2017-01-20 16:02:49 +0000] [9809] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2017-01-20 16:02:49 +0000] [9809] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

**/var/www/myproject/myproject/myproject/myproject/myproject.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os
from os.path import abspath, dirname
from sys import path
SITE_ROOT = dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__)))
path.append(SITE_ROOT)

from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', "settings.production")

from django.conf import settings  

app = Celery('myproject')

path.append('/var/www/myproject/myproject/myproject')
# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')

# load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

**/var/www/myproject/myproject/myproject/myproject/__init.py__**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .myproject import app as celery_app

# __all__ = ['celery_app']
```

**Error after commenting out `from .myproject import app as celery_app:**

```
[2017-01-20 18:13:49 +0000] [1411] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.4.5
[2017-01-20 18:13:49 +0000] [1411] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (1411)
[2017-01-20 18:13:49 +0000] [1411] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2017-01-20 18:13:49 +0000] [1439] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1439
[2017-01-20 18:13:49 +0000] [1439] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 515, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 122, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 130, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 357, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named myproject.wsgi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 515, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 122, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 130, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 357, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named myproject.wsgi
[2017-01-20 18:13:49 +0000] [1439] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 1439)
[2017-01-20 18:13:49 +0000] [1411] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2017-01-20 18:13:49 +0000] [1411] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

It seems that now gunicorn is having a hard time finding any modules.

Comment: do you have any debug trace of what error happened behind the curtain? by that I mean an error log from gunicorn.

Comment: Just added some error info, maybe it has something to do with Celery?

Comment: yes, you need to look into that import error. Maybe remove the relative import in __init__.py? as it can't import, gunicorn cannot run the python code, so nginx can't connect to it, and you get the 502.

Comment: Great that worked! Any idea why my celery import would suddenly stop working since all I did was remove an upstream folder that wasn't really doing anything besides housing the appspec.yml file?

Comment: I guess some path somewhere wasn't changed to reflect the directory structure?

Comment: by the way, it'd be nice to answer your own question with what you did, so that others can benefit from the answer as well!

Comment: Will do once this gets resolved! Unfortunately, I have a new error after restarting the EC2 instance...it seems that the fix only worked temporarily, now there's a new issue importing `myproject.wsgi` (see update to question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that `gunicorn.conf` was not pointing to the directory with `manage.py` in it. So I changed it to:

```
description "Gunicorn application server handling myproject"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
setuid ubuntu
setgid ubuntu
chdir /var/www/myproject/myproject

exec /usr/local/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 myproject.wsgi:application --env SECRET_KEY=""
```

Which solved the issue. See [Django Docs - How to use Django with Gunicorn](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/gunicorn/), which states that your project should be on the Python path; the simplest way to ensure that is to run this command from the same directory as your manage.py file.